# How can I shorten this SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT 
    lesson_id_1, 
    lesson_id_2, 
    lesson_id_3, 
    lesson_id_4, 
    lesson_id_5, 
    lesson_id_6, 
    lesson_id_7, 
    lesson_id_8, 
    lesson_id_9, 
    lesson_id_10  
FROM hub_attendance 
WHERE 
    student_id='351' AND 
    course_id = '102' AND 
    (
        lesson_id_1 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_2 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_3 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_4 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_5 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_6 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_7 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_8 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_9 = 300 OR 
        lesson_id_10 = 300
    ) 
LIMIT 1
```

I know it's not pretty but this is my MySQL statement. I am trying to find the lesson_id_xx where it = 300. How can I hone in so that it just returns the single lesson_id_xx and not all of them?

This is what it returns right now:

```
array(10) { 
    ["lesson_id_1"]=> string(3) "279" 
    ["lesson_id_2"]=> string(3) "292" 
    ["lesson_id_3"]=> string(3) "293" 
    ["lesson_id_4"]=> string(3) "294" 
    ["lesson_id_5"]=> string(3) "295" 
    ["lesson_id_6"]=> string(3) "296" 
    ["lesson_id_7"]=> string(3) "297" 
    ["lesson_id_8"]=> string(3) "298" 
    ["lesson_id_9"]=> string(3) "299" 
    ["lesson_id_10"]=> string(3) "300" 
}
```

I just want this:

```
array(10) {
    ["lesson_id_10"]=> string(3) "300" 
}
```

Comment: Do you have 10 lesson_id columns?

Comment: Don't ask, it's just the way this table is set up. It's horrible I know

Comment: are you serious? I agree with @hakre `"Is this trolling?"`

Comment: @hakre: that is a great idea. I need to come up with a question that demonstrates master level proficiency in one area, but novice level incompetence in another closely related area.

Comment: You should really really really normalize your schema.

Answer (score 2):

Not much help, but you can shorten your `where` clause by using `in`:

```
SELECT
    lesson_id_1, lesson_id_2, lesson_id_3, lesson_id_4, lesson_id_5, 
    lesson_id_6, lesson_id_7, lesson_id_8, lesson_id_9, lesson_id_10  
FROM hub_attendance 
WHERE 
    student_id='351' AND course_id = '102' AND
    300 in (lesson_id_1, lesson_id_2, lesson_id_3, lesson_id_4, lesson_id_5,
            lesson_id_6, lesson_id_7, lesson_id_8, lesson_id_9, lesson_id_10) 
LIMIT 1
```

However, I think the real answer is that you need to re-design and normalize this table if you want to make querying it any easier.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to take this up with the lead developer lol. So obvious  I'm going to have even more problems later. Can't believe he's expecting me to actually work with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about a table (hub_attendance) where you have a lot of lesson_id_xx columns that represent the lessons that a student will be taking i.e. there are different lesson options for a given course that students can choose from. Is this right? If so, the proper way to shorten this statement is to redesign your tables according to proper relational principles so that you have two tables:

```
hub_attendance:
id, student_id,  course_id

attendance_lesson:
attendance_id,  lesson_id
```

This attendance_lesson table is a join table representing a many-to-many relationship, i.e. one lesson can have many attendances and one (course) attendance can have many lessons.

Your SQL will then look like this (assuming you want all attendances for the lesson with id of 300):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM hub_attendance 
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                FROM attendance_lesson 
               WHERE attendance_lesson.lesson_id = 300 
                 AND attendance_lesson.attendance_id = hub_attendance.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want.. once you added something in `Select` there is no way back as far as I know :)

P.S: You should realllllllllly redesign your database and don't let this table like this... It's offending (and will offend) lots of programmers...

Answer (score 0):

apparently it **ought** to be something like

```
SELECT a.*,group_concat(lesson_id) FROM hub_attendance a, hub_lessons l
    WHERE h.id=l.aid AND lesson_id = 300 GROUP BY aid
```